# Autoplay audio file cannot be disabled whatever I do

Tags: html, audio, embed, autoplay

I'm using this code to incorporate an audio file on my website, but the autoplay is always active, no matter what I do.

```html
<embed autostart="false" type="audio/mpeg" loop="true" height="35" src="http://prefeitojuninho.com.br/site/wp-content/themes/juninho45/audio/45-sou-eu.mp3"></embed>
```

How can I deactivate  the autoplay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<video width="340" height="80" controls preload="none">
   <source src="http://prefeitojuninho.com.br/site/wp-content/themes/juninho45/audio/45-sou-eu.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Run it in a function and only call the function when you want to play it. It seems like you have it in the global scope, so it is going to play automatically.